# Find if an array is a sequence in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given an array which might contain duplicates, How can we find if it is a sequence?

Eg. `{7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2}`

is a sequence `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

Sorting is an obvious solution. How can we do this in O(n) time and O(1) space?

Answer (score 10):

assuming `1,2,3,3,4,1` is a valid unsorted sequence and `2,4,6,8` is a valid sequence (of step two) as well, but `1,3,5,9` isn't (7 is missing) and assuming the input array can be overwritten,

1. determine the maximum and minimum: O(n) time, O(1) space. You can use the first and the last position of the array for this.
2. determine the step. The step is the least common multiplier of all `a_n - min`
3. if they are too far apart (`max - min > (count + 1) * step`), this cannot be a sequence. Otherwise,
4. do an in-place integer sort. Until start > end:

   - look at the first position. Let the value there be `v_0`
   - let its target position when we assume no duplicates (`(v_0 - min) / step + start`) be `i`

     - if the target position is less than `start`, it's a duplicate. Move it to the back and decrement the end pointer
     - if the target position is more than `end`, some element is missing in the sequence. Claim the array is not a sequence.
   - if the element is at the target position, increment the start pointer and the `min` reference
   - else if the element at the target position is less than the reference minimum or equal to `v_0`, swap it to the end of the array and decrement the end pointer. It's a duplicate.
   - else swap the element at the target position with `v_0`.
5. Claim the array a sequence

The in-place integer sort is O(n). In each step it either:

- shortens the input array and keeps all sorted elements at their target positions or
- sorts one or two previously unsorted elements to their target position.

At the end of sorting, each element is either a duplicate in the duplicate block, or at its correct position in the sorted block.

Note that step #3 can be left out. #4 will correctly determine this is not a sequence, albeit slower.

If the step has to be 1, then this algorithm can be simplified somewhat (see revision #1)

Comment: Oh, I noticed the answer I just posted seems to be an implementation of this ;)

Comment: This is actually a generalization of the solution I had posted. Hence why I deleted my post. Excellent answer.

Comment: Everything that makes me feel like a complete idiot is pretty awesome !

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm (Python) destroys the original array, but otherwise satisfies O(n) time and O(1) extra space.

```
# INPUT: An array 'arr' of N integers.
# OUTPUT: If the array consists exactly of the integers
#         S, S+1, ..., S+N-1, for some S, in any order,
#         then modifies 'arr' into a sorted array and returns it.
#         Otherwise, returns False, and 'arr' may have been modified.
def sort_sequence (arr):
    the_min = min(arr)
    the_max = max(arr)
    if the_max - the_min != len(arr) - 1:
        return False
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i] -= the_min
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        while arr[i] != i:
            j = arr[i]
            t = arr[j]
            if t == j:
                return False
            arr[j] = j
            arr[i] = t
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i] += the_min
    return arr
```

I have not formally proven that it works yet.

Why is this O(n)? In the final double loop, after an element is first put into its correct spot, it can only be visited one more time - either at the beginning of another inner loop where it is seen to be in the right spot, or where it is found to be in the way of a duplicate element (the `if t == h` part).

Comment: This looks similar to [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18102484/499214) except you are assuming a step of 1 and you're disallowing duplicates. The latter is clearly against the spec.

Comment: @JanDvorak well, the question is ambiguous, it just says the array might contain duplicates, and not how they are to be interpreted. In any case I stated in the comments exactly which problem my algorithm is supposed to solve.

Comment: @JanDvorak similarly the question doesn't say anything about step size. I think if the intent was to allow any step size, it would have been written in terms of arithmetic progression.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak It's a recollected interview question, there's a lot of room for omission of or incorrect details there, and a small change for a more generic solution is probably better / more likely to land you that job.

Answer (score -1):

Let my try:

1. Determine min and max – O(n)
2. Make an array of nullable values of the size of the original array – O(n) (Yes, missing space requirement here)
3. Iterate over the original array (O(n)) and put the number you find at index (number - min), if you find a value there, you don't have a sequence, if you come to an end and no position was claimed, you have a sequence

```C#
public bool IsSequence(int[] values)
{
    var min = values[0];
    var max = values[0];
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        min = min > value ? value : min;
        max = max > value ? max : value;
    }

    if ((max - min + 1) != values.Length)
        return false;

    var testingArray = new int?[values.Length];
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var index = value - min;
        if (testingArray[index].HasValue)
            return false;
        else
            testingArray[index] = value;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Step 2 uses space O(n).

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18102484/499214 Step #2 sounds like you're trying to go out of `O(1)` space by allocating an unbounded amount of extra memory.

Comment: OK, missed space requirement